# KMZ File with Icon

Tags: icons, kml, google-earth, kmz

I'm trying to put an icon in a KMZ file so the user can view a thumbnail when they click on the pinpoint. I have the following code - It's working, but isn't showing the icon/thumbnail. I've looked at the Google Developers and can't see a difference. Just need a second pair of eyes to view it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
<name>Evidence File</name>
<description>SAMSUNG - GT-I9000
2012:10:25 17:36:57
2797 KB
Height: 2448 Pixels
Width:  3264 Pixels
C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\FYP Cases\M2510\IMG_20121025_163656.jpg</description>
<IconStyle><scale>1.1</scale><Icon><href>C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\FYP Cases\M2510\IMG_20121025_163656.jpg</href></Icon></IconStyle>
<Point>
<coordinates>-2.6172222222222223,51.43</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an absolute reference to the file in your KML file (C:\Users\Steve...). If image is inside your KMZ then you should reference the relative file location instead. Also, the file path C:... is not a valid URL which should be of the form http:// or file:// if using an absolute URL.

Let's assume the KMZ file has two entries (in this order):

- doc.kml
- IMG_20121025_163656.jpg

The IconStyle within the doc.kml should be rewritten like this:

```
<IconStyle>
    <scale>1.1</scale>
    <Icon>
        <href>IMG_20121025_163656.jpg</href>
    </Icon>
</IconStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. That helps a lot.